Cancel transaction if remote client is gone
Is there any way to cancel transaction if remote client is gone?
@RestController
class Controller {
  ...
  @PostMapping("/do/thing")
  public Response doThing() {
      ...
      return businessLogicService.performAction();
  }
}

@Service
class BusinessLogicService {
   ...
   public Response doThing() {
      ...
      var pieceOfData = restClient.callExternalService();
      ...
      transactionTemplate.execute(status -> {
          dao.save(pieceOfData);
      })
      ...
      return response;
   }
   ...
}

The problem is that sometimes performAction() works longer than usual (REST calls to external service are retried, transactionTemplate waits for free connection in Hikari pool, etc.)
Remote client (consumer of our REST API) get a read timeout and "forget" about us, but our service doesn't have any clue about it - the method completes successfully, a state in database has been changed (entity is persisted), and when Spring MVC machinery serializes DTO and tries to write it to socket, we have an exception "connection has been closed by the remote peer".
As a result, we have inconsistency between us and our consumer - we have a succesfull booking in our DB, but they are not.
Maybe there is some pattern to handle such a thing?

Yes, it's call "provide confirmation". Don't consider a booking final until the client system confirms it is through a secondary rest call.

@Gimby How does it solve the inconsistency problem? Imagine a situation - a client performed the second call, we changed the state in our database and commited, but client did not get our response because of network issues and didn't changed state of his own database. We have the same inconsistency
